# How do I write a formula for the "Predefined Field Value" for a create an Event Quick action?

Tags: formula, event, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have a Custom Object; Property, and I have created a Quick Action to create a new Event record related to the Custom Object.

I want to populate the Description Field of the new Event Object with Field information from the Property Record.

With the error I have I don't really understand how I am doing the formula wrong?

[image: Attempt 1]

[image: Attempt 2]

Comment: What is your expected behavior? Are you trying to concatenate some values after merging them in? The syntax isn't really close enough to precisely guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, I Just want to import the values from a few fields into the Description from the Custom Object

Answer (score 2):

You have the following problems:

- Do not wrap fields in double quotes
- You concatenate strings using the `&` operator
- You can add line breaks using the `BR()` function

Corrected:

```
Property__c.Site_Contact__c & BR() &
Property__c.Property_Group__r.Name & BR() &
etc...
```

Comment: That is super helpful - I added an image to the OP to show what is happening, the field information isn't coming in, just the API name for the field

Comment: @OliverHuntsman, update your formula to _not_ wrap the fields in quotes. That will force the formula to treat them as regular text. You can copy and paste Adrian's example to get you started: `Property__c.Site_Contact__c & BR() &
Property__c.Property_Group__r.Name & BR()`. If you see the right contact and group names with that, then you should be all clear to add the additional fields to your formula.